Angular - trying to make last form control not required when using Reactive forms and Arrays - with add and delete buttons
This doesn't quite work.
I'm have an array of date pairs (start) and (end), and load three initially, and have two buttons, add and delete. The add button adds a new pair, but only if the last form group (which the pair of dates are in) is valid.
This works, but I want to be able to:
Make last element (the 3rd element) when the component is loaded, editable and to remove the validator.required condition from that control
Then when I add a 4th pair, I want to make the 3rd end date, non-editable, and add the validator.required condition, bu the 4th end date should be editable with the required condition.
Basically, the last end-date should always be optional (not required) and editable.
I'm struggling to get Angular to do this, for some reason, the last end date element is always required and never editable.
Sample code
protected addDatePair() {
    const datesArray = this.datesInfo.get('datesArray') as FormArray;

    if (datesArray.length > 0) {
      const lastFormGroup = datesArray.at(datesArray.length - 1) as FormGroup;

      if (lastFormGroup && lastFormGroup.valid) {
        // add date to array in class
        this.datesArray.push(9);

        // create new end date control
        const newEndDateControl = new FormControl(null, {
          nonNullable: false,
          validators: [],
        });
        newEndDateControl.reset();
        const newFormGroup = this.datePairs();

        // swap new control into new form group
        newFormGroup.removeControl('endDate');
        newFormGroup.addControl('startDate', newEndDateControl);

        // add new form group to dates array
        datesArray.push(newFormGroup);

        // should probably only initialise new element, rather than all again
        this.formGetters = this.initFormGetters(this.datesInfo);

        // should probably initialise new error state matcher too

        // need to add delay since,
        // asynchronouse HTML may not have rendered the 4th element to DOM
        // (a bit annoying!)
        // I'd like to make the last End Date (i) modifiable and (ii) not required
        setTimeout(() => {
          const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(
            'div[formArrayName="datesArray"] ' + 'input[id^="endDate"]'
          );
          const lastInput = inputs[inputs.length - 1] as HTMLInputElement;
          if (lastInput) {
            lastInput.removeAttribute('readonly');
            lastInput.removeAttribute('required');
            lastInput.removeAttribute('aria-required');
          }
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        console.log('last formGroup is not valid');
      }
    } else {
      // TO IMPLEMENT
    }
  }

  protected removeLastDatePair() {
    // TO IMPLEMENT
  }

Here is my stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-y2b7mc?file=src%2Fmain.ts
I want the delete button to do the same / similar thing.

There has been a lot of changes made, but the gist is the below points.
When running the for loops, just use the controls array and not the data array.
We can simplify most of the complex code into smaller functionality by just running for loops.
We should not use required in HTML because these are reserved for template driven validations, but we are using reactive forms here.
Please go through the code and let me know if doubts.
Please adapt the code based on your use case, I'm sure I did not exactly achieve what you wanted!
TS
import { Component, DestroyRef, inject, Signal } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, DatePipe, JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroupDirective,
  FormGroup,
  NgForm,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  ValidationErrors,
  ValidatorFn,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  MatError,
  MatFormField,
  MatHint,
  MatLabel,
  MatSuffix,
} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {
  MatDatepicker,
  MatDatepickerInput,
  MatDatepickerToggle,
} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatOption } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';
import {
  DateAdapter,
  ErrorStateMatcher,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
} from '@angular/material/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  MomentDateAdapter,
  MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS,
} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import 'zone.js';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

type FormGetters = {
  startDate: FormControl<string>;
  endDate: FormControl<string>;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormField,
    MatLabel,
    MatDatepickerInput,
    MatInput,
    MatError,
    MatDatepicker,
    MatDatepickerToggle,
    MatHint,
    MatSuffix,
    MatOption,
    MatSelect,
    JsonPipe,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
  ],
  templateUrl: `main.html`,
})
export class App {
  private formBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);

  name = 'Angular';

  /* data properties */
  datesArray = [1, 2, 3];

  /* form properties */
  protected datesInfo: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({});
  protected formGetters: FormGetters[] = [];
  errorMatcher = new SingleErrorStateMatcher('startDateAfterEndDate');

  /* error state matchers */
  readonly startDateAfterEndDateMatchers: SingleErrorStateMatcher[] = [];

  /* lifecycle hooks */
  protected ngOnInit(): void {
    // initialisation
    this.initFormGroup();
    this.formGetters = this.initFormGetters(this.datesInfo);
  }

  // INITIALISE FORM
  private initFormGroup() {
    this.datesInfo = this.formBuilder.group({
      datesArray: this.formBuilder.array(
        (this.datesArray || []).map((_, i) =>
          this.datePairs(this.datesArray.length - 1 === i)
        )
      ),
    });
  }

  get datesArrayControls() {
    return (<FormArray>this.datesInfo.get('datesArray'))
      .controls as FormGroup[];
  }

  private datePairs(isLast: boolean): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      startDate: [
        null,
        {
          nonNullable: true,
          validators: !isLast
            ? [Validators.required, this.startDateAfterEndDateMatcher]
            : [],
        },
      ],
      endDate: [
        null,
        {
          nonNullable: true,
          validators: !isLast
            ? [Validators.required, this.startDateAfterEndDateMatcher]
            : [],
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  protected addDatePair() {
    const datesArray = this.datesInfo.get('datesArray') as FormArray;
    (<FormGroup[]>datesArray.controls).forEach((formGroup: FormGroup) => {
      const startDateCtrl = formGroup.get('startDate') as FormControl;
      const endDateCtrl = formGroup.get('endDate') as FormControl;
      startDateCtrl.clearValidators();
      startDateCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
      endDateCtrl.clearValidators();
      endDateCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
      endDateCtrl.disable();
      startDateCtrl.disable();
    });
    datesArray.push(this.datePairs(true));
  }

  protected removeLastDatePair() {
    const datesArray = this.datesInfo.get('datesArray') as FormArray;
    datesArray.controls.splice(datesArray.controls.length - 1, 1);
    (<FormGroup[]>datesArray.controls).forEach(
      (formGroup: FormGroup, i: number) => {
        const startDateCtrl = formGroup.get('startDate') as FormControl;
        const endDateCtrl = formGroup.get('endDate') as FormControl;
        if (datesArray.controls.length - 1 !== i) {
          startDateCtrl.clearValidators();
          startDateCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
          endDateCtrl.clearValidators();
          endDateCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
          endDateCtrl.disable();
          startDateCtrl.disable();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  // FORM GETTER
  private initFormGetters(form: FormGroup) {
    const datesArray = this.datesInfo.get('datesArray') as FormArray;
    const formGetters: FormGetters[] = [];

    datesArray.controls.forEach((control: AbstractControl) => {
      if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        const formGetter: FormGetters = {
          startDate: control.get('startDate') as FormControl<string>,
          endDate: control.get('endDate') as FormControl<string>,
        };

        formGetters.push(formGetter);
      }
    });

    return formGetters;
  }

  // VALIDATORS
  public startDateAfterEndDateMatcher: ValidatorFn =
    this.dateComparisonValidator(
      'startDate',
      'endDate',
      'startDateAfterEndDate',
      (date1: Date, date2: Date) => date1 && date2 && date1 > date2
    );

  private dateComparisonValidator(
    fieldName1: string,
    fieldName2: string,
    errorName: string,
    condition: (value1: any, value2: any) => boolean
  ): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const field1: FormControl = control.parent?.get(
        fieldName1
      ) as FormControl;
      const field2: FormControl = control.parent?.get(
        fieldName2
      ) as FormControl;
      const field1Value = field1?.value;
      const field2Value = field2?.value;
      console.log('condition', condition(field1Value, field2Value));
      if (condition(field1Value, field2Value)) {
        const errors: ValidationErrors = {};
        errors[errorName] = true;
        return errors;
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}

// ERROR MATCHER
export class SingleErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  private errorCode: string;
  public constructor(errorCode: string, private formGroup?: FormGroup) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }

  isErrorState(
    control: FormControl | null,
    formGroup: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null
  ): boolean {
    let parentFormGroup = this.formGroup ?? formGroup;
    //console.log('parentFormGroup', parentFormGroup);

    return !!(control?.invalid && control?.touched);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
});

HTML
<!-- Add Button -->
<button (click)="addDatePair()" [disabled]="datesInfo.invalid">
  Add Date Pair
</button>
<!-- Delete Button -->
<button (click)="removeLastDatePair()" [disabled]="datesInfo.invalid">
  Delete Date Pair
</button>

<!-- dates info -->
<form [formGroup]="datesInfo" class="form-group">
  <!-- dates array -->
  <div formArrayName="datesArray">
    @for (date of datesArrayControls; track $index) {
    <ng-container [formGroupName]="$index">
      <!-- start date -->
      <mat-form-field class="form-date">
        <!-- label -->
        <mat-label> Start Date </mat-label>

        <!-- input -->
        <input
          matInput
          [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker"
          [errorStateMatcher]="errorMatcher"
          formControlName="startDate"
          autocomplete="off"
        />

        <!-- hint -->
        <mat-hint>DD/MM/YYYY</mat-hint>

        <!-- picker -->
        <mat-datepicker-toggle
          matIconSuffix
          [for]="startDatePicker"
          [disabled]="false"
        ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker
          #startDatePicker
          [startAt]="date?.get('startDate')?.value"
        ></mat-datepicker>

        <!-- errors -->
        <mat-error
          *ngIf="date?.get('startDate')?.invalid
                  && (date?.get('startDate')?.dirty || date?.get('startDate')?.touched)"
        >
          @if(date?.get('startDate')?.errors?.['required']) { Start Date is
          required. }
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error
          *ngIf="date?.get('startDate')?.hasError('startDateAfterEndDate')"
        >
          Cannot be after End Date
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <!-- end date -->
      <mat-form-field class="form-date">
        <!-- label -->
        <mat-label> End Date </mat-label>

        <!-- input -->
        <input
          matInput
          [matDatepicker]="endDatePicker"
          [errorStateMatcher]="errorMatcher"
          formControlName="endDate"
          autocomplete="off"
        />

        <!-- hint -->
        <mat-hint>DD/MM/YYYY</mat-hint>

        <!-- picker -->
        <mat-datepicker-toggle
          matIconSuffix
          [for]="endDatePicker"
          [disabled]="false"
        ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker
          #endDatePicker
          [startAt]="date?.get('startDate')?.value"
        ></mat-datepicker>

        <!-- errors -->
        <mat-error
          *ngIf="date?.get('endDate')?.invalid && (date?.get('endDate')?.dirty || date?.get('endDate')?.touched)"
        >
          @if (date?.get('endDate')?.errors?.['required']) { End Date is
          required. }
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error
          *ngIf="date?.get('endDate')?.hasError('startDateAfterEndDate')"
        >
          Cannot be before Start Date
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error
          *ngIf="date?.get('endDate')?.hasError('endDateExceedsStartDate')"
        >
          End Date cannot exceeds any Start Date
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </ng-container>
    }
  </div>
</form>

Stackblitz Demo

Yes, I like this solution where you add the logic inside the dates formBuilder, with the boolean. It's halfway there. When you add a new pair of dates though, the 2nd last one, that did have no required validator, should then have one. Same when you delete, if the 2nd last item did have a validator before deleting the last, once the last is deleted, the validator should be removed from 2nd last. Hope that makese sense? Here is my updated SB. Your errorMatchers needed to be in an array, attached to the formGroup sas well. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zburb9?file=src%2Fmain.ts

@Sachin There is  no need for a error state matcher to be an array, please make the changes you need and raise a new question with future doubts

You need separate error state matchers for each date pair? As they are attached to a formGroup. Otherwise, attaching one to all the date pair formgroups, will trigger all formGroups, if there is an error? I'm also still working out how to add the validator to the 2nd last date pair (after a new date pair is added)

@Sachin I think a single one is enough! you are just using a class, material will instantiate it within its internal code, so each element, has its own unique instance! As far as I know its (start less or equal to validator) already added, try it out on my code!

Maybe only one is needed, but you need to attach it to the formGroup, so if one field fails, both will be highlighted red, since the condition depends on both. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zburb9?file=src%2Fmain.ts (although still working out how to use one error matcher, attached to formGroup...as that seems more elegant)

@Sachin To handle that scenario, all you need to do, is add a (change) handler for both the form fields, when one changes, it marks the other one as touched and update value and validity!

I guess so, that would mean adding a change handler for every field though...

@Sachin This is my methodology, you are free to explore other methods!
